# delegate covariance and Contavariance

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance

Consider the following code snippet

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

public delegate TResult Function<in T, out TResult>(T args);

 class Program
 {
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program pg =new Program();
        Function<Object, DerivedClass> fn1 = null;
        Function<String, BaseClass> fn2 = null;
        fn1 = new Function<object, DerivedClass>(pg.myCheckFuntion)
        fn2=fn1;
        fn2("");// calls myCheckFuntion(Object a)
        pg.myCheckFuntion("Hello"); //calls myCheckFuntion(String a)
     }

     public DerivedClass myCheckFuntion(Object a)
    {
        return  new DerivedClass();
    }
    public DerivedClass myCheckFuntion(String a)
    { 
        return new DerivedClass();
    }
 }
```

why the delegate call and normal method invocation call different methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The delegate is bound to `myCheckFuntion(Object)` at compile time - you're telling it to find a method which accepts an `Object`. That binding is just to a single method - it doesn't perform overload resolution at execution time based on the actual argument type.

When you call `pg.myCheckFuntion("Hello")` *that* will bind to `myCheckFuntion(String)` at compile-time because `"Hello"` is a string, and the conversion from string to string is preferred over the conversion from string to object in overload resolution.

Note that if you write:

```
object text = "Hello";
pg.myCheckFuntion(text);
```

then *that* will call `myCheckFuntion(Object)`.

Comment: There's just nothing to add. +1

Comment: @siride: yeah, I've found it in hard way - by trying :)

Answer (score 2):

`fn2` calls the `myCheckFuntion(Object a)` because of its declaration:

```
fn1 = new Function<object, DerivedClass>(pg.myCheckFuntion)
fn2 = fn1; // here you copy the reference
```

`pg.myCheckFuntion("Hello");` calls the `myCheckFuntion(Object a)` because the `String` is more restrictive type than `object`.

if you cast string to `Object`:

```
pg.myCheckFuntion((object)"Hello");
```

it will call other method.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate object itself still only points to just one function, not to a range of functions.  The co(ntra)variance only allows you to point it at a larger domain of function types.  In the same way, you can assign all sorts of values to a variable of type `object`, but fewer to a variable of type `string`.  Even so, a variable will still only have one actual type and one actual value at any given time.